# How to find the classes of the currently selected node?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a node `parentNode`

```
var parentNode = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode
```

With JQuery, how can i get a list of all the classes of the node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `parentNode` is a dom element referece, In modern browsers you can use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```
parentNode.classList
```

or use [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) and split

```
parentNode.className.split(/\s+/)
```

Comment: Seems like parentNode.classList[0] is returning the actual names of the classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you explicitly asked for a jQuery solution, wrap the node in the jQuery selector:

```
var parentNode = $(window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode);
```

Then you can use jQuery methods like this:

```
var classes = parentNode.attr("class");
```

Which returns all the classes as a string.  If you need an array with all the classes, use `.split()`

```
var classesArray = classes.split(' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want a jQuery solution, here are a few lines of code which may help you.

```
node = $('div');

classes = node.attr('class').split(' ');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/xag0fgmb/)